# How to change localhost URL in Hybris Sitemap XML

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, xml-sitemap

I am trying to create a sitemap.xml for my Hybris site by going out of the box way and copying the ImpEx given in out of the box store in my site.impex.

**How to change localhost URL in Hybris Sitemap XML?**
The sitemap.xml generated after running the cronjob consists of multiple  tags, which in turn contain the location of the different sitemap page types. Here in product and categories, most of the products and categories are visible, but the issue here is that they begin with localhost. Should this behavior be changed in higher environments? If so, how to do this?

**How to add custom page URL to hybris sitemap?**
Besides, in our pages, we have several content pages and also some custom pages, which do not feature there. How to add these in sitemap.xml?

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure site domains in **local.properties** config file.

```
website.my-site-id.http=http\://www.mydomain.com\:9001/
website.my-site-id.https=https\://www.mydomain.com\:9002/
media.my-site-id.http=http\://www.mydomain.com\:9001/
media.my-site-id.https=https\://www.mydomain.com\:9002/
asm.my-site-id.http=http\://www.mydomain.com\:9001/
asm.my-site-id.https=https\://www.mydomain.com\:9002/
```

Comment: @myskoft,thanks a lot for your answer.Really appreciate it.How to address the second point of fixing the content pages and custom pages not featuring?

Comment: If your custom page developed in standard way (pages listed in CMS), it will included your sitemap. Otherwise you need custom development for sitemap. I suggest to fix custom page generation like hybris way.

Comment: @myskoft,thanks a lot for your answer.Really appreciate it.However,I saw that in my configuration:                                                                             
              website.my-site-id.http=https://www.example.com
              website.my-site-id.https=https://www.example.com                                                                    where my-site is the uid in CMSSite for my site.Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @myksoft,the configuration parameters have the entry:                                                                                  
                  website.mysite.http=https://www.example.com                                            
                  website.mysite.https=https://www.example.com                                        where mysite is the uid of the CMSSite.If this configuration is correct,why isn't it relecting on the <loc> tag of <sitemap>

Comment: The localhost coming was resolved by making a missing entry:                                                      
                                                                  media.my-site-id.http                                                           
                                                                  media.my-site-id.https

Answer (score 1):

> Should this behaviour be changed in higher environments?If so, how to
>   do this?

Yes, you can configure below properties in your local.properties file according to your environments

```
website.mysite.http=http://www.yourDomain.com
website.mysite.https=https://www.yourDomain.com
media.mysite.http=http://www.yourDomain.com
media.mysite.https=https://www.yourDomain.com
```

here, replace mysite with your CMSSite id.
These properties internally used by `getWebsiteUrlForSite` & `getMediaUrlForSite` method of the `DefaultSiteBaseUrlResolutionService`

---

> Besides,in our pages,we have several content pages and also some
>   custom pages,which do not feature there.How to add these in
>   sitemap.xml?

Go to HMC/backOffice > WCMS > WebSite > select your website > Right click on
Site Map Configuration > Open in new tab.

Here, you can add custom URL in your SiteMapConfig and add Custom as Site Map Type
Like

[image]

Site map type:**Custom** internally call `CustomPageSiteMapGenerator` which fetch the above configured custom URLs list