# Creating a sitemap for SAP Commerce and Spartacus

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, sap-cloud-platform, spartacus-storefront, xml-sitemap

Does anyone know what I need for my SAP Commerce project in order to provide a sitemap on the url {basesite}/sitemap.xml? Our project has Spartacus for front-end, and therefore no acceleratorstorefront extension, but we do have acceleratorservices that seems to come with a part of the sitemap functionalities.

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you solve your issue? I am stuck with the same requirement.

Answer (score 2):

As of today (2020-05-07), sitemaps are not available. It is up to the crawler to crawl the site.

See these discussions on Slack:

- https://spartacus-storefront.slack.com/archives/CD16V16FR/p1576091082480600
- https://spartacus-storefront.slack.com/archives/CD16V16FR/p1576154711491300

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is a cronjob which seems to generate a sitemap. Here is the belonging [class link](https://help.sap.com/doc/a4265d5ea8314eb2929e6cf6fb8e35a5/1811/en-US/de/hybris/platform/acceleratorservices/cronjob/SiteMapMediaJob.html).

Also here is another stackoverflow thread. [How to change localhost URL in Hybris Sitemap XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918926/how-to-change-localhost-url-in-hybris-sitemap-xml)

**UPDATE**

This is for the jsp storefront, not Spartacus

Comment: I think this is only for the OOTB Hybris/JSP storefront, not Spartacus